# Is there an example of converting a mathematical statement into a three color mapping?

Tags: graph-colorings, proof-theory, np

https://youtu.be/5ovdoxnfFVc?t=1118

At this point, prof Wigderson says it is easy to go from a mathematical statement to a graph coloring problem. The video does not provide an example of this, and a brief read of the referred papers just confused me further.

For example, Is there a simple way to state the infinitude of primes as a graph coloring problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Questions should be self contained.  In particular, some explanation should be given of the content and context of the linked video.

Comment: An almost-identical question was asked on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025685/how-do-you-turn-a-proof-of-a-mathematical-statement-into-a-zero-knowledge-proof?noredirect=1#comment8311079_4025685

Answer (score 6):

The kind of mathematical statement you can convert into a three-coloring problem has the form

> There exists a proof of that there exist infinitely many primes, in the formal system Peano Arithmetic, using at most 1,000,000 symbols.

We can replace "there exist infinitely many primes" with another mathematical statement, "Peano Arithmetic" with another formal system, and "1,000,000" with another number.

This is done by a step-by-step conversion process.

(1) Write a computer program that inputs a proof of length at most 1,000,000 in your formal system, and outputs "True" if it follows the rules of deduction and proves your desired statement, and "False" if the proof is invalid in any way.

For many formal systems, such computer programs actually exist and are used by computer scientists and mathematicians.

(2) Simulate the computer program on a circuit made of AND, OR, and NOT gates.

This is closely related to, but not quite the same as, what we have to do to build computers that actually run our computer programs. One big difference is that transistors in a computer can be used more than once, inputting and outputting different values, but in a circuit each gate can be used once. This can be handled by just making as many copies of a gate as needed.

(3) Replace each AND, OR, and NOT gate by an appropriate "gadget" piece of the graph, so that 3-colorings will flow through the graph just the way true and false values flow through the circuit.

The final size of the graph will end up being, for a reasonable circuit, at most a polynomial in the starting value N=1,000,000. But it's clear from all the steps we had to do that it might be a really big polynomial, and the graph is not going to be small enough that it will function as a reasonable example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
Steps 1 and 2 are clear to me now, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean by saying replace each AND, OR and NOT gate by an appropriate gadget, or what it means for three colorings to flow.

Comment: @Abhishekcherath The best approach is to look at pictures of the gadgets and think about how you can color them. You can find them in any introduction to the proof that graph 3-coloring is NP-complete. (Well, they will usually explain how to get 3SAT clauses rather than circuit gates, but it's the same principle, and you can use one to produce the other).

Comment: Is there a name for this approach so that I can use as a keyword for searching about it?

Comment: @geckos I think "gadgets" together with "NP-complete" or words relevant for a particular problem will help, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadget_(computer_science). CircuitSAT is also a keyword relevant to step (2).

Comment: @WillSawin Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Thanks @WillSawin I never heard about gadgets in this context, thank you!